# How can I use dojo.destroy and dojo.create in a phone validation scenario?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a problem where I have a phone input field that is connected to a dojo dropdown widget. You can select a US phone type or a International phone type. If you select the Us type you can only enter 10 characters in the input field. If you select the International type you can put 15 characters in the input field. This is working correctly in Firefox and Internet Explorer 8 but not working correctly in Internet explorer 7.

here is the html code:

```
<input id="tPhone" type="text" name="tPhone" class="isCompleted phone-number" tabindex="0" maxlength="10" rel="i13"/>
```

I figure I can get it working right in dojo if I dynamically alter or destroy the dom node and replace it based on the selection the user makes. How can I do this with dojo? Here is my dojo code that I have now:

```
this.phoneTypeDrop = new widget.StyledDropdown(dojo.byId("sPhoneType"),function(){
        if(_this.phoneTypeDrop.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
            Phone.pnField.regEx = Validation.regExps.phone;
            dojo.attr(dojo.byId(Phone.pnField.id),"maxlength", 10);
        }else{
            Phone.pnField.regEx = Validation.regExps.phoneInternational;    
            dojo.attr(dojo.byId(Phone.pnField.id),"maxlength", 15);
        }
},true,64);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. IE can be a pain. I check with the help of a colleague and IE7 excepts a different syntax than other browsers for maxlegnth. It uses maxLegnth a capital "L". So the code looks like this now:

```
this.phoneTypeDrop = new widget.StyledDropdown(dojo.byId("sPhoneType"),function(){
    if(_this.phoneTypeDrop.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
        Phone.pnField.regEx = Validation.regExps.phone;
        dojo.attr(dojo.byId(Phone.pnField.id),"maxLength", 10);
    }else{
        Phone.pnField.regEx = Validation.regExps.phoneInternational;    
        dojo.attr(dojo.byId(Phone.pnField.id),"maxLength", 15);
    }
},true,64);
```